# Euler angles transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, rotations

I have three Euler angles which represent the rotations of a point in a given reference system; and the first and third angles are not bounded in any range, meaning they encode the information about the number of turns the point has undergone.

How can I express these rotations in a second reference system, preserving the information about the number of turns?

Comment: Are these coordinates uniquely specified?

Comment: Yes they are. In particular (I don't think it is particularly useful to know this detail, but just to put things in perspective) they are derived as an output of a FEM analysis, and I need to post process them to compute them in another reference system.